# crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]

Tags: c#, api, debugging, blazor

I'm doing a Blazor course and find myself stuck witha  bug i can't fix.

I just developed a controller that should be callable through API but I can't seem to call that API. I used Postman to test it and am receiving an error message: "An unhandled error has occurred."

instead of a list of units (it's a game). I believe it depends from a different bug that may make the list un-callable.It is my first experience with this language and I am finding it quite difficult to figure the issue or at least triage the issue.Especially because i have about 0 previous experience with .net or Java. The code create a web application (opens my browser). In the Console of the Browser I received the Error Messages:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at BlazorBattles.Client.Services.UnitService.LoadUnitsAsync() in C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\BlazorBattles\BlazorBattles\Client\Services\UnitService.cs:line 37
   at BlazorBattles.Client.Pages.Build.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\BlazorBattles\BlazorBattles\Client\Pages\Build.razor:line 33
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
window.Module.s.printErr    @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
Fe._internal.dotNetCriticalError    @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
St  @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @   dotnet.6.0.10.95x5mwwwq1.js:1
$func219    @   00971d2a:0x1a492
$func167    @   00971d2a:0xce60
$func166    @   00971d2a:0xbd73
$func2815   @   00971d2a:0xabebf
$func1619   @   00971d2a:0x6fc80
$func1617   @   00971d2a:0x6fbf2
$func970    @   00971d2a:0x50643
$func219    @   00971d2a:0x1a44b
$func167    @   00971d2a:0xce60
$func166    @   00971d2a:0xbd73
$func2815   @   00971d2a:0xabebf
$func1619   @   00971d2a:0x6fc80
$func1623   @   00971d2a:0x702ed
$mono_wasm_invoke_method    @   00971d2a:0x969f
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @   dotnet.6.0.10.95x5mwwwq1.js:1
managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_BeginInvokeDotNet    @   managed__Microsoft_A…eginInvokeDotNet:19
beginInvokeDotNetFromJS @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
b   @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
e.invokeMethodAsync @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonym)    @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
ve  @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
we  @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonym)    @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonym)    @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
onGlobalEvent
```

You can find all of my code in [Github] under https://github.com/maxbiocca/BlazorBattles/tree/master/BlazorBattles

It seams to be not happy with the expression "Task LoadUnitsAsync();" as part of the public interface IUnitService. I am not understanding where the issue is or where i am missing a reference since I do not get any error messages in my Visual Studio.

The issue appears also in UnitService. I copied the code of those 3 elements down below (UnitControler, IUnitService, Unitservice) The issue occurs also in two other "pages" that I didn't attach.

I am stuck in this since 3 days and can't find a way to move forward. I would love your help, thanks!

IUnitService

````
    
     
    ```
     using BlazorBattles.Shared;
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;

     namespace BlazorBattles.Client.Services
     {
     public interface IUnitService
      {
         IList<Unit> Units { get;  }
         IList<UserUnit> MyUnits { get; set; }
         void AddUnit(int unitId);
         Task LoadUnitsAsync();
      }
     }
     ```
````

UnitService

```
using BlazorBattles.Shared;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Linq;

namespace BlazorBattles.Client.Services
{
public class UnitService : IUnitService
{

  //     private readonly HttpClient _http;

    //public UnitService(HttpClient http){

 //            _http = http;
   //}

    public IList<Unit> Units => new List<Unit>
    {
        new Unit() {Id=1, Title = "Knight", Attack=10, Defense=10, BananaCost=100},
        new Unit() {Id=2, Title = "Archer", Attack=15, Defense=5, BananaCost=150},
        new Unit() {Id=3, Title = "Mage", Attack=20, Defense=1, BananaCost=200}
    };
    public IList<UserUnit> MyUnits { get; set; } = new List<UserUnit>();

   


    public void AddUnit(int unitId)
    {
        var unit = Units.First(unit => unit.Id == unitId);
        MyUnits.Add(new UserUnit { UnitId = unit.Id, HitPoints = unit.HitPoints });

    }

    public Task LoadUnitsAsync() 
    {   
        throw new Exception();
    } 



    //public async Task LoadUnitsAsync(){
    //if (Units.Count == 0)
    //{
    //  Units = await  _http.GetFromJsonAsync<IList<Unit>>("api/Unit");
    //}
    //}
 }
 }
```

UnitControler

```
using BlazorBattles.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BlazorBattles.Server.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UnitController : ControllerBase
{
    public IList<Unit> Units => new List<Unit>
    {
        new Unit() {Id=1, Title = "Knight", Attack=10, Defense=10, BananaCost=100},
        new Unit() {Id=2, Title = "Archer", Attack=15, Defense=5, BananaCost=150},
        new Unit() {Id=3, Title = "Mage", Attack=20, Defense=1, BananaCost=200}
    };
   // [HttpGet]
    //public IActionResult GetUnits()
    //  {
    //      return Ok(Units);
    // }

  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have code commented out?  What errors were you getting before you started to comment out the code?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to this question, but Google led me to this post while searching for the error message:
For anybody who sees this post in the future and has a "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]" error message:

In my case the problem was a missing pair of parantheses.
Not working:

```
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="xyz.IsBilingual" onclick="@(() => UpdatePreview)" />
```

Working:

```
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="xyz.IsBilingual" onclick="@(() => UpdatePreview())" />
```

Function:

```
void UpdatePreview() {...}
```

Compiler didn´t notice a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've just looked at your code. Within `BlazorBattles/Client/Pages/Build.razor` you are calling `LoadUnitsAsync();` within line 33.

However this functions is implemented like this in your service:

```
public Task LoadUnitsAsync() 
{   
     throw new Exception();
}
```